# Thévenin's theorem for voltage divider bias

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, passive-networks

I am calculating the base current of transistor Q1. To simplify the circuit equations, I applied Thévenin's theorem and converted V1 and R1, R2 into Vth and Rth as shown in the image.

Vth = V1 x (R2 / R1 + R2); Rth = R1 || R2

[image]

After application of Thévenin's theorem, the equations are converted into Ib as below:

(Vth - Va / 1.955K) = Va / 1.24k + Ib

Va = 0.7 + (hfe +1) x Ib x 200... Substituting the value of Va into above equation:

Ib = 232 μA

The base current value is not as per the simulation, not even close to it.

(Q1 is in active region and confirmed in simulation.)

Is the application of Thévenin's theorem wrong in this circuit?

Should thr following three loops be taken into considerations for KVL technique?

Loop 1: V1-R1-R2

Loop 2: R3-R4-R2

Loop 3: 9V1-R1-R3-Va

Any suggestions are highly appreciated to find Ib.

Comment: I dont think what you have posted is correct.

Comment: You have to do the Thevenin twice. Once for V1 and R1 and R2 (Vth 1 and Rth1) and the second time on (Rth1 + R3), R4 and Vth1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the equivalent circuit as seen by the base.
$$R_{TH}=((1.6||2.377)+1) || 1.24=0.759 k\Omega$$
To find the Thevenin voltage, I will use linearity
$$ 1.24*\frac{2.24}{1.24}=2.24 V$$
$$ 2.24+1.6k(\frac{2.24}{2.377}m+1m)= 5.35V$$
$$12*\frac{12}{5.35}*2.24=5.03 V$$
So
$$5.03-0.7-759I_b-41*200I_b=0$$
$$I_b=483 \mu A$$
$$I_c=40*483=19320 \mu A=19.32 mA$$
$$24V-19.32 mA*10 \Omega=23.8068 V =V_C$$
$$5.03-759*483 \mu = 4.66V = V_B $$
Clearly, the BC junction is reverse biased, so this is in the active mode.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Does your simulation give you something close to my answer?